# C# How to sort multiple objects

Tags: c#, sorting

1. Ask the user how many sellers he wants to so assign.
2. Get sellers name, id, city and how many apples he have sold, for each seller he wanted to assign.
3. Create 4 levels based on how many apples sold. level 1 under 50 apples, level 2 between 50-99 apples, level 3 between 100-199 apples and level 4 over 199 apples.
4. When all sellers are assigned sort each person by how many apples they have sold, from low to high.
5. Print out each sellers information (name, id, city, apples sold) and which level they are on and how many sellers there is in the same level.

Example:

```
name: daniel
id: 18886
city: chicago
apples sold: 30
1 seller have reached level 1: under 50 apples


name: elno
id: 18843
city: chicago
apples sold: 212

name: noel
id: 1567
city: chicago
apples sold: 230
2 seller have reached level 4: over 199 apples
```

Now this is how my code looks like, i just dont know how to sort everything accordingly when writing it out on the console

```
public class Seller 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Apples { get; set; } 

}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi and Welcome to The Garden!");
        Console.WriteLine("How many sellers would u like to assign?");

        int Assign = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Seller[] NewSeller = new Seller[Assign];

        for (int i = 0; i < Assign; i++) 
        {

            NewSeller[i] = new Seller();

            Console.WriteLine("______________________________");

            Console.Write("Enter name for seller" + i + "\nName: ");
            NewSeller[i].Name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Enter id for seller " + i + "\nID; ");
            NewSeller[i].Id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter city for seller " + i + "\nCity: ");
            NewSeller[i].City = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Enter apples sold for seller " + i + "\nApples: ");
            NewSeller[i].Apples = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Assign; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("__________________________________________________________");
            Console.WriteLine("|   Seller {0} |" , i);
            Console.WriteLine("|--------------");
            Console.WriteLine("| Name: {0}", NewSeller[i].Name);
            Console.WriteLine("| ID: {0}", NewSeller[i].Id);
            Console.WriteLine("| City: {0}", NewSeller[i].City);
            Console.WriteLine("| Apples sold: {0}", NewSeller[i].Apples);
            Console.WriteLine("__________________________________________________________");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to sort the `NewSeller` before printing. For the sake of completeness look at the `Array.Sort` and `IComparer<T>`

Comment: Why do you use array? Did you try to google for "c# array sort" ? With `List<T>` it would be easier.

Comment: Are you allowed to use built-in sorting routines like `Array.Sort` or Linq? Either of those would be a one-liner but since this seems to be a learning exercise I wanted to make sure.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, really appriciate it! i have tried all of them but i just cant get my head around to do it so that the codes works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Linq to sort the seller and get the Level details

```
//Sort the seller and get the Level details
var results = sellers.OrderBy(s => s.Apples)
                     .Select(x => new
                            {
                                x.Name,
                                x.Id,
                                x.City,
                                x.Apples,
                                Level = x.Apples < 50 ? 1 : x.Apples < 99 ? 2 : x.Apples < 199 ? 3 : 4,
                                LevelDetails = x.Apples < 50 ? "under 50" : x.Apples < 99 ? "over 50" : x.Apples < 199 ? "over 99" : "over 199"
                        }); 

//Iterate the sorted list
foreach (var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("__________________________________________________________");
    Console.WriteLine("|   Seller {0} |", results.ToList().IndexOf(result) + 1);
    Console.WriteLine("|--------------");
    Console.WriteLine("| Name: {0}", result.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("| ID: {0}", result.Id);
    Console.WriteLine("| City: {0}", result.City);
    Console.WriteLine("| Apples sold: {0}", result.Apples);
    Console.WriteLine("| {0} seller have reached level {1}: over {2} apples", results.Where(x=>x.Level==result.Level).Count(), result.Level, result.LevelDetails);
    Console.WriteLine("__________________________________________________________");
}
```

Comment: Thank u sir, i will try this method and try to understand it!

Comment: Krishna Mupalla sir, i forgot to mention that i first need to print out all the sellers in level 1 and then printing out how many sellers that are in the that level.                         and not like printing how many sellers that are in that level after printing out each person. i hope u can help me with this sir

Comment: i saw that the guy who edited my example did it wrong, i have now corrected it

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a homework assignment :)

The easiest way to sort collections is with LINQ, via a Lambda expression:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8

I would also recommend using string interpolation as it is more concise and easier to understand:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

In your case, you would do something like this:

```cs
public class Seller 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Apples { get; set; }



}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi and Welcome to The Garden!");
        Console.WriteLine("How many sellers would u like to assign?");

        int Assign = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Seller[] NewSeller = new Seller[Assign];

        for (int i = 0; i < Assign; i++)
        {
            NewSeller[i] = new Seller();

            Console.WriteLine("______________________________");
            Console.Write($"Enter name for seller {i}: ");
            NewSeller[i].Name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write($"Enter id for seller {i}: ");
            NewSeller[i].Id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write($"Enter city for seller {i}: ");
            NewSeller[i].City = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write($"Enter apples sold for seller {i}: ");
            NewSeller[i].Apples = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        //default sorting is ascending, so low to high. use OrderByDescending when you need high to low
        Seller[] sortedList = NewSeller.OrderBy(s => s.Apples).ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedList.Length; i++)
        {
            Seller currentSeller = sortedList[i];
            Console.WriteLine("__________________________________________________________");
            Console.WriteLine($"|   Seller {i} |");
            Console.WriteLine("|--------------");
            Console.WriteLine($"| Name: {currentSeller.Name}");
            Console.WriteLine($"| ID: {currentSeller.Id}");
            Console.WriteLine($"| City: {currentSeller.City}");
            Console.WriteLine($"| Apples sold: {currentSeller.Apples}");
            Console.WriteLine("__________________________________________________________");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hahah yes it is a homework assignment. really appriciate your help, i will try it, and see if i can try to understand!